# Batch file - List Files by extension

Tags: batch, recursive

I am looking to get a total number of files by extension in a folder that contains many subfolders.

Example Output:

.doc: 6 files 
.xls: 10 files

etc

I want to either output the results into a txt file or simply display them. Is this possible via batch? Thanks!

So far I have

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do set cnt=%%A
echo File count = %cnt%
```

But that only gives me the total number of files, I am looking for more info such as by extension and the path to the files.

Comment: Do you know what extensions you are looking for? Or just every possible file extension?

Comment: I don't. I am looking to get info about all the extensions.